# $\bar G=\frac{G}{\gamma_2G^p}$ is of class at most 2 when G is not powerful

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be finite p-group of class c and order $p^n$ that is not powerful then $\gamma_2\not\le G^p$ (second lower central series is not contained in $G^p$)
Let $\bar G=\frac{G}{\gamma_2G^p}$
How we can say $\bar G$ is a two-generator group of exponent p and class at
most 2?

Comment: Actually, $\bar{G}$ is abelian of exponent $p$ (or elementary abelian).  You can not deduce that $\bar{G}$ is $2$-generated under these assumptions.

Comment: how we know $\bar G$ is elementary abelian?